# How to tell Flask (.flaskenv) which python to use

Tags: python, macos, flask, environment-variables, environment

I have a flask project and specified a `.flaskenv` file like this:

```
FLASK_APP=my_program.py
FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

*I'm running this on a MacOS system with Python 3.8.x.*

I'm calling `flask run` to start the program. This works fine, but I want the program to run in a **conda environment**, however, no matter in which conda environment I'm using, the program will always run in the **local python environment**.

Just using `python my_program.py` will work and use the desired **conda environment** that is active in the shell.

But, if possible, I would like to specify the python environment that is used when calling `flask run`. 
**Is there some way to specify the desired python environment for example in `.flaskenv`?**

---

***Edit:**


Installing `flask` via `conda` in the respective environment solved the problem for me. For further details see answer by @VPfB and comments.*

Comment: Are you using Python virtual environment to run?

Comment: I think it is too late for selecting an environment when the `flask` has been started already. `flask` is a script with a shebang line specifying the python executable to run. You could have several `flask` scripts though.

Comment: @PuneetSingh I'm using conda environment.

Comment: @VPfB I tried setting a shebang in my `my_program.py` but this did not have any effect.

Comment: @MBT the shebang (`#!`) is an instruction for the shell only. From Python's view it is just a comment.

Comment: @VPfB Thanks for your reply! So you think there is no way to change that? Do you know why it is taking the local installation in the first place?

Comment: @MBT I think so, but I know conda only a little. (I wrote two flask apps that are in use). Each environment where your application is runable must have `flask` package installed. The package includes the `flask` script (in the `/bin` subdirectory). If you want to start the app with `flask run` either call the script with full path or modify the PATH variable.

Comment: @VPfB Great! Now I got it, thanks! I didn't really realize that `flask` actually was a python package installed at some environment..
I installed flask via conda in the right environment, this solved the issue. If you like, you can write a brief answer so that I can accept it.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the `flask` Python script is not able to select the environment it will run inside, because it is a part of some environemnt.

The script contains startup code which imports the entry point function from the `flask` library (package) and invokes it. The script is part of the package and the package is installed in some Python environment (or system-wide).

In order to be able to run a flask app in multiple environments, it must be installed in each of them.